# How to render a template in a module controller?

Tags: 8, page-controller

I want to render a custom template in a module controller but I don't know how. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to let Drupal know about the theme, and then you can leverage it in the controller code. The template needs to be in the folder my_module/templates.

my_module.module

```
function my_module_theme() {
  $theme['template_name'] = [
    'render element' => 'build',
    'template' => 'template_file_name',//This is only needed if you need a different template file name than the array key above, 'template_name'.
  ];

  //override existing template for this module
  $theme['html__my_module__template_file_name'] = [
    'template' => 'html--my_module--template_file_name',
  ];
  return $theme;
}
```

src/Controller/MyModuleController.php

```
public function index() {
  $build['#theme'] = 'template_name';
  //populate your build renderable array..
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Correct but the more common use case is variables, would be good to adapt that and e.g. include a variable and also how to specifically set it in the render array. Also, template is the default now in 8.x and no longer need to specified explicitly.

Comment: Great! the content of the populate is displayed in the Bartik theme, how about if I want the template content to be displayed without to extend the Bartik theme ?

Comment: @Berdir - what do you mean by template is the default now?

Comment: @Lhassan Baazzi, you'll need to override surrounding templates such as page.html.twig by creating your own module version called page--my_module--template_file_name.html.twig and then declare it in your hook_theme() like we did with the above template.

Comment: @blakphyre Drupal 7 automatically assumed a theme function with the same name if you did not specificy a template key. Drupal 8 automatically assumes a template with the same name(with _ => -, so template_name becomes template-name.html.twig) *unless* you specificy the function key explicitly.

Comment: @Berdir I see what you're saying, I'll amend my answer to show that - I'm not sure about other other part, including a variable and passing it through the render array. I haven't done that yet myself.

Comment: @blakphyre how I can declare it ? some code please, for example for this templae `html.html.twig`

Comment: @LhassanBaazzi I've included code above to show how to declare it. You'll need to create that template in your module 'html--my_module--template_file_name.html.twig'.