# Custom template not used for custom entity generated with Drupal Console

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have created a custom entity via drupal console, and it created template `item_entity.html.twig` in template folder, but the entity is being rendered in some other way because any changes in template not work. How to make it rendered through the CREATED custom template?

Edit:
After editing hook_theme as [here](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3878#issuecomment-384552938) suggested the problem was solved.

Comment: These links may help you: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182567/how-to-render-a-template-in-a-module-controller && https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module

Comment: Creating a custom entity using drupal console does not create/update your `MODULE_theme()` I guess its by design.  You should add/update your theme function to pick up your template.  Look in this issue for more details https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3878#issuecomment-384552938

Comment: Thank you, Giorgosk your suggestion solved my issue.